# The player's coordinates are not displayed in debug list, how can I find them without commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I went through all the settings of the Minecraft, but did not find any settings for the debug list

Well, maybe a couple of settings for the type of Profiler, etc.

The essence does not change, a solid chunk of the data about coordinates, lighting, condition of the unit, all disappeared, this is as it should be in this version?

Versions where tested-,1.13.2, 1.15.2

And by the way, hidden commands like displaying chunks or hitboxes don't work for me either

I didn't know how to solve this problem.

Result:Tell me how to solve this problem?

[image: Close-Up Shot]
[image: FurtherShot]

Answer (score 27):

You have gamerule `reducedDebugInfo` set to `true`. This will get rid of some of the info on your debug screen, including XYZ coordinates.

Type the following command into the chat to turn it off:

```
/gamerule reducedDebugInfo false
```